# split the parent element if the keyword found in xml file using perl

Tags: xml, perl

> **Question Updated**

I have a keyword tag `<split/>` in the xml file. Base on this I need to split the elements to be closed which has been opened and Also I need to open *DUMMY OPENING TAGS* which we are adding the closing tags on the keyword elements.

For eg. Input:

```
<section>
   <para> The para sample lines...
      <list>
     <list-item><para> ..... .... </para></list-item>
     <list-item><para> ..... .... </para></list-item>
     <list-item><para> ..... <split/> .... </para></list-item>
      </list>
     The para sample lines.. </para>
</section>
```

Expected Output:

```
<section>
   <para> The para sample lines...
      <list>
     <list-item><para> ..... .... </para></list-item>
     <list-item><para> ..... .... </para></list-item>
     <list-item><para> ..... </para></list-item>
      </list>
   </para>
</section>
*<split/>*
<section> <!--dummy tag-->
   <para><!--dummy tag-->
      <list><!--dummy tag-->
     <list-item><para><!--dummy tag--> <split/> .... </para></list-item>
      </list>
      The para sample lines.. </para>
</section>
```

> Note: Asterisks for just identification purpose only (need to delete the tag)

I am very new in using Module based on the Markup Languages. Could someone help me to get the idea. (I am also trying...)

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: Come with your code, it would be easy for people to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of how you could do this using `XML::Twig`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $first_doc = XML::Twig -> parse ( \*DATA ); 

my $second_doc = XML::Twig -> new; 
$second_doc -> set_root ( $first_doc -> root -> copy ); #create a copy. 

while ( my $after_split = $first_doc -> get_xpath('//split',0)->next_sibling ) {
   $after_split -> delete;
}

$first_doc -> get_xpath('//split',0) -> delete; # delete split tag.

while ( my $before_split = $second_doc -> get_xpath('//split',0)->prev_sibling ) {
   $before_split -> delete;
}

$second_doc -> get_xpath('//split',0) -> delete; # delete split tag. 

$first_doc -> set_pretty_print ('indented_a');
$first_doc -> print;

print "\n--- second doc ---\n"; 
$second_doc -> set_pretty_print ('indented_a');
$second_doc -> print;


__DATA__
<section>
   <para>
      <list>
      <list-item><para> sample content for first doc <split/> second doc sample content </para></list-item>

      </list>
   </para>
</section>
```

This gives you as output:

```
<section>
  <para>
    <list>
      <list-item>
        <para> sample content for first doc </para>
      </list-item>
    </list>
  </para>
</section>

--- second doc ---
<section>
  <para>
    <list>
      <list-item>
        <para> second doc sample content </para>
      </list-item>
    </list>
  </para>
</section>
```

You will probably want to look at `parsefile` and `sprint` from `XML::Twig` to handle reading your own file, and generating output.

Note - this does a 'full split' of the document into essentially two separate documents - but this technique should work withing a subtree, because the core of it is locating your `split` element, and deleting everything before or after it as necessary.

Comment: Awesome champ its working fine. Just need to ask a query is, how to retain the indentation which as it is in the input file?

Comment: How I print in a sample input file

Comment: You can't maintain the original indentation, because you're modifying the content. And indentation is semantically irrelevant. You can just change the output options to not format, which might preserve it, at least partially.

Comment: Something going wrong hence I have updated the question could you please revisit the question.

Comment: So use the code I've given you as a starting point, and have a go at it? If you've tried, then post what you've got so far and where/what problems you're hitting. But maybe explain quite what you're trying to accomplish with your `<split/>` because this looks a lot like an XY problem.